# is it fair for a questioner to delete a question after several people have worked hard to resolve it

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions, vote-to-delete

Presumably [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26874063/c-or-operator-not-working) was deleted because the answer turned out to be embarrassingly obvious (in their mind). LIke

```
for(int i = 0; i < ct; i++);
{
    printf("%d", i);
}
```

But not that simple because people would have spotted it.

In many cases people have tried to help and spent some time hacking away, then the question disappears. Now I don't know what the answer was, I am curious; plus others might have found it useful

Original question:

> #### C++ OR operator not working
>
> I have some C++ code and for some reason i can't get the OR operator
>   to work...
>
> ```
> if (
>   (this->keyboardManager->isKeyDown(VK_LEFT) == true)
> || 
>   (this->keyboardManager->isKeyDown(0x41) == true)
> )
> ```
>
> Now both of these work on there own but when i combine them both wont
>   trigger the if statement so both of these work. `if
>   (this->keyboardManager->isKeyDown(VK_LEFT) == true)` and
>   `if(this->keyboardManager->isKeyDown(0x41) == true)`
>
> But the top one wont work.
>
> My ***KeaboardManager::isKeyDown***
>
> ```
> return (GetAsyncKeyState(key) & 0x8000) ? 0 : 1;
> ```

Are there rules about preventing deletion, if somebody ups it or favorites it?

Comment: What specific question? Do you still have a link to it? 10k+ users can still see deleted posts, so we can at least get some context. Deletion takes multiple votes, so *more than one* community member felt it wasn't worth keeping around.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26874063/c-or-operator-not-working

Comment: and of course just because it was not deleted doesn't mean that the questioner will post the answer

Comment: The **original author** deleted the post.

Comment: No, it's bloody annoying, especially if the question is deleted while I'm typing in my humungous answer.

Comment: He reposted [it here](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/87149/c-directx-winapi-getkeystate-with-2-inputs-breaks).  Your answer was wrong btw.

Comment: @HansPassant: and that copy is now deleted too. That OP cannot seem to make up their mind as to what they want with that post.

Comment: I wouldn't really call your answer something that had a lot of work put into it. If you are really eager to know the answer you can just post a question yourself that shows the same problem.

Comment: No, it is not fair.  SE is however more concerned whether it is fair for the next thousand programmers to be exposed to that Q+A when Google directs them to such a question.  Let's call it pre-emptive fairness.  And no, it would be absolutely horrible if they landed on *that* one.

Comment: I'm with @MartinJames here. I often prepare an answer to a deserving question, to find the author removed it. It would be better to keep *all* questions, even if they can be edited out with the history still available. Answering **HansPassant** comment above, simple questions can still have useful and valid answers. This would also deal with the "homework" situation where the question is deleted as soon as the student has a useful answer. If I post a comment in my local online newspaper, only the moderator can delete it. To hack an old saying: *"email in haste, repent at leisure."*

Answer (score 4):

The question author deleted the question themselves. Perhaps they solved it, and did not think it was worth sharing the solution, or it was a silly mistake they rather not have anyone see.

Questions can be deleted by their owner until there are multiple answers, or a single answer with at least one up vote. Voting on the question or marking it as a favourite does not prevent such deletions, nor should they.

Yes, it can sometimes be annoying that a question disappears while you are adding an answer. It happens occasionally. You move on to other questions more worthy of help.

Comment: thats my answer - which I deleted cos after further thought I did not think it was right

Comment: @pm100: right, so what exactly is the problem here? You want to prevent the question owner from deleting their question? Until there are valuable answers, the work is entirely their own and can delete at will.

Comment: i want(ed) to know the real answer. If somebody posted an answer that is. You have actually answered my main question - if there is at least on upvoted answer then the question becomes sticky - which is good. BTW He deleted the repost of the question

Answer (score 2):

I entirely 100% agree this is £$%$%^$%^ annoying!!!!!!

However (*breathe, 10, 9, 8..*) I'm not sure what can be done about it without causing a great change, and/or introducing additional issues.

A very simple example:
You could for example stop users from deleting their questions for the first 48 hours, giving users searching the newer questions a bit of time to either answer, or move on.

However, users might answer, and get upvotes, which means you are introducing the scenario whereby the questioner cannot remove their question.
Is this ok to do?

etc, etc

---

Come up with a brilliant solution, propose it, and you will likely get good backing.
You have my vote* for a start!

<sub>(* Disclaimer: could be up*vote* or down*vote*, depending on how good the proposal is)</sub>